# NsAttributed String in iOS with UITableViewCell?(More Then 1500 Row)

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I have a scenario in my application where I need to show more than 1000 rows in `UITableView` and each cell has an html string to show.

Right now I have used a simple approach to parse the htmlString in `NSAttributedString` but that approach is making the `UITableView` scroll very slow and freezes the `UITableView` for some seconds.

I have also thought about parsing the html string prior to use in `UITableView` and storing it in some local storage, but as it is more than 1000 rows and it could be increased in future this approach is taking lots of time to store the `NSAttributedString`.

Is there any other suggestion that I can use in this scene?

Shall I only show some Bold and Color tag only in my string and exclude other tag? If so, how?

Shall I use `UITextView` that will make things Easy? Or maybe `UIWebView`?

please share your views

I am using this simple approach right now I know this is not standard approach.

Following is my Sample String

```
> <b>Working Towards: </b>The pupil can answer 9 when asked 'I have
> eaten 8 grapes and eat one more. How many have I
> eaten?'<br><br/><b>Meeting: </b>The pupil can answer 27 when asked 'I
> have 28 grapes and eat one of them. How many are
> left?'<br><br/><b>Exceeding: </b>The pupil can answer 27 when asked 'I
> have 29 grapes and eat two of them. How many are left?'
```

In my `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
NSString *tempObjectiveName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<font size=\"4\" color=#AAAAAA>%@</font>",currentObjective.name];
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[tempObjectiveName dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
lbl_description.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: Some code to look at would be nice... How do you create your attributed strings? What kind of strings are they? When exactly do you create them?

Comment: @andlin please check my updated question.

Comment: Have you tried creating the NSAttributedString in a background thread? Maybe that will get rid of your performance problem.

Comment: yes it will but for loading thousands of string in background mode its not a good idea either and its behave odd when scrolling too fast

Comment: I meant creating the attributed string in a background thread in the cellForIndexPath method, so that it's not created until it's actually needed for display (and then caching the result, so that you won't have to create it again). I'm guessing that you're not showing thousands of rows at the same time?

Comment: How different are the strings? Do they have a common structure? Could you do something different all together, like multiple labels? Show the code for your attributed string creation and data storage.

Comment: yes i have made that solution but its not working fully proper way if scrolling is too fast or in rough way